# Capturar el user logeado para pasarlo como varible en un forms.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Amigos soy nuevo en Django y estoy realizando un formulario que captura el first_name y last_name automaticamente y se le pasa al forms.py para que cuando renderice en el html lo muestre.
tengo en mi forms.py asi:

```
    full_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Nombre Completo",
                            min_length=4, max_length=50,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                "class": "form-control",
                                "placeholder": "Nombre de Usuario",
                                "name": "nombre_completo",
                                "readonly": "True",
                                "value": "carlos"
                        }))
```

Ahore el value deberia capturarlo desde el usuario logeado, espero me puedan ayudar y me orienten mas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la vista inicializa el **form** con la información que ya tiene **request.user**

```
form = TestForm(
    initial={
        'full_name': '{} {}'.format(
            request.user.first_name, 
            request.user.last_name
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: Amigo funcionas de maravilla gracias